# Android: How to keep recording while switch between back and front camera?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, video-recording

Video is limited in 1 minute.
What I already try, I restart record after switch camera, so there are several video files, in the end, I append them one by one using mp4parser. 
But in the final video, I get a up down video in the front camera part. I have no idea what's go wrong!
I have another thought is to record what I preview like record screen, but I have no idea how to implement it as First time camera player , like remove not needed UI.
If there is any advice would be great help. Thank your guys anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use jprofiler for performance monitoring and recording. I am using the same. Its amazing.